Pytorch: matrices are equal but have different result
How is this possible?
>>> torch.all(w1 == w2)
tensor(True)
>>> torch.all(i1 @ w1.T == i1 @ w2.T)
tensor(False)

The matrices are all the same dtype, on the same device, etc:
>>> i.dtype, w1.dtype, w2.dtype
(torch.float32, torch.float32, torch.float32)
>>> i.device, w1.device, w2.device
(device(type='cpu'), device(type='cpu'), device(type='cpu'))
>>> i.shape, w1.shape, w2.shape
(torch.Size([3, 4096]), torch.Size([14336, 4096]), torch.Size([14336, 4096]))
>>> diff = (i @ w1.T) - (i @ w2.T)
>>> diff
tensor([[ 1.6391e-07, -5.3644e-07,  3.8743e-07,  ...,  4.7684e-07,
         -5.9605e-08, -3.8743e-07],
        [ 3.5763e-07,  2.9802e-08, -4.7684e-07,  ...,  8.6427e-07,
          8.9407e-08, -1.1921e-07],
        [ 3.5763e-07,  3.4273e-07, -4.4703e-08,  ...,  2.1607e-07,
          2.3656e-07,  7.4506e-08]], grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
>>> torch.max(torch.abs(diff))
tensor(7.1526e-06, grad_fn=<MaxBackward1>)
>>> torch.all(w1 - w2 == 0)
tensor(True)

Seeing PyTorch Same Input Different Output (Not Random), I also set:
>>> torch.manual_seed(0)
>>> torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
>>> torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False

This didn't change anything.
For context, I discovered this while debugging a difference between two different implementations of Mixtral. So i corresponds to what's called current_state and w1 is expert_mlp.W_gate.T, while w2 is the corresponding matrix from the Huggingface implementation of Mixtral (where it's called w1, confusingly).

This isn't a full answer, but worth mentioning that cuda will use different matmul algos based on the layout of tensors in memory. results that are not exactly bitwise equal are common

Karl's comment lead me to the answer. The two matrices had a different stride(), which must have lead Pytorch to choose a different order of operations (I'm satisfied with this level of understanding).
We can reproduce this with .T.contiguous().T:
w = hf_model.layers[0].block_sparse_moe.experts[0].w3.weight
w2 = w.T.contiguous().T
i = torch.randn(3, 4096)

>>> torch.all(i @ w.T == i @ w2.T)
tensor(False)
>>> w.stride(), w2.stride()
((4096, 1), (1, 14336))

Full ipynb gist
